# What is wrong with this .htaccess? Too many redirects on Safari

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can someone pls say me where my .hatcess has a problem?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|js|json|eot|svg|ttf|woff|txt|xml|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteRule . core/FrontController.class.php [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /index http://eese.com
```

The problem: Safari says i have to many redirects (Just go to http://eese.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Redirect` rule with your `mod_rewrite` rules. Change your .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|js|json|eot|svg|ttf|woff|txt|xml|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteRule . core/FrontController.class.php [L]
```

Test this out after clearing your browser cache.